# Horizontally center 'ul' in a 'div' with max-width WITHOUT centering 'li's using CSS only

Tags: html, css

We are using `max-width` on our `ul` to limit the number of li's displayed on a single line to 5. The `ul` should always be centered in our `div`, hence `margin:0 auto`.

This works fine on screens >=`max-width`. How do we get our `ul` to center in our `div` on screens less than `max-width` WITHOUT centering our li's?

Here's our html:

```
<div id="wrapper-team">
    <ul id="liste-team">
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here our CSS:

```
#wrapper-team{width:100%; margin:0 auto;}
ul#liste-team{display:block; max-width:1432px; margin:0 auto; padding-top:5px;}
ul#liste-team li{display:inline-block; width:280px; height:280px; list-style-type:none; margin:0 3px 5px 0;}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You could use [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to specify different CSS behaviours depending on the screen width.

Comment: for clarity - You are saying that you are opposed to the idea of putting `text-align: center` on `ul#liste-team` - correct?

Comment: @Joel: that's right. The 'li's have to be aligned left within the 'ul' and 'text-align: center' will center them in the 'ul'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `min-width` property.

```
ul#liste-team{display:block; min-width: 980px; max-width:1432px; margin:0 auto; padding-top:5px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a media query for desktop resolutions or another min resolution.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) 
{   
#wrapper-team{width:100%; margin:0 auto;}
ul#liste-team{display:block; max-width:1432px; margin:0 auto; padding-top:5px;}
ul#liste-team li{display:inline-block; width:280px; height:280px; list-style-type:none;     
margin:0 3px 5px 0;}
}
```

Comment: I was hoping not to have to resolve to media queries!! Is there no other CSS solution...??